# ASP.NET Core Build error

Tags: asp.net, .net-core-rc2

Working with the new, latest and greatest ASP.Net CORE RC2.

Following the Get Started sample : https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html.

I get a build error run the Scaffolding Nuget command :
Scaffold-DbContext "'Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;'" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

The error is :
C:\Code\EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.ExistingDb\src\EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.ExistingDb\error CS0041: Unexpected error writing debug information -- 'Windows PDB writer is not available -- could not find Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll'

Doing a clean build returns the same result.

NuGetted this package :
Install-Package Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native -Pre

and referenced in project.json :

```
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
"version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
  "type": "platform"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native": "1.4.0-rc2"
},
```

Yet still get the same result.

dotnet restored, Googled the problem *ad nauseum*.

WTF.

Comment: Downloaded the sample project, it works fine for me. Dumb questions but did you install the new .NET Core RC2? Do you have the correct Nuget feed in your Visual Studio settings? https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json You don't need to add Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native to your project.json, the project should work without any modification.

Comment: RC2 is installed. Stupid question : what is the procedure for updating the Nuget feed.  The procedure outlined on the nuget.org site is not clear. Tnx.

Comment: In Visual Studio: Tools -> Options -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Sources

Comment: The feed has been updated but the app will not build. It fails with the same error.

Comment: Success : uninstalled Visual C++ 2015, downloaded and reinstalled a  fresh copy of Visual C++ 2015 Redistrbutable (x64) -14.0.23026. https://www.microsoft.com/en-hk/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Comment: It actually helped,i didn't even reinstall,just 'Repaired' my Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable